# Cannot edit .accdb I can only see File and Home on the Access ribbon

Tags: database, ms-access

I Cannot edit .accdb I can only see File and home on the Access ribbon, but when I open access with a new project I have the complete menu. 
Can anyone help me? I need to change some stuff in the codes and tables.

Comment: This belongs on SuperUser.StackExchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try holding down shift key when you double click on the file. Hold shift whilst the file loads. This should enable the ribbons and navigation pane. You can then go in to options and re-enable them if you require to do so.

Comment: I should add, if this database has been designed so the user cannot access the tables, then make sure you have permission to make alterations.

Comment: Thanks LiamH. You solved my probleme: ) BIG THANKS.